# pandas to_datetime convert datetime string to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a column in a `df` which contains `datetime` strings,

```
inv_date
24/01/2008
15/06/2007 14:55:22
08/06/2007 18:26:12
15/08/2007 14:53:25
15/02/2008
07/03/2007
13/08/2007
```

I used `pd.to_datetime` with format `%d%m%Y` for converting the strings into `datetime` values;

```
pd.to_datetime(df.inv_date, errors='coerce', format='%d%m%Y')
```

I got

```
inv_date
24/01/2008
0
0
0
15/02/2008
07/03/2007
13/08/2007
```

the format is inferred from `inv_date` as the most common datetime format; I am wondering how to not convert `15/06/2007 14:55:22`, `08/06/2007 18:26:12`, `15/08/2007 14:53:25` to 0s, but `15/06/2007`, `08/06/2007`, `15/08/2007`.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.inv_date.str[:10], errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y')` ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regular `pd.to_datetime` call then use `.dt.date`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.inv_date).dt.date
0    2008-01-24
1    2007-06-15
2    2007-08-06
3    2007-08-15
4    2008-02-15
5    2007-07-03
6    2007-08-13
Name: inv_date, dtype: object
>>>
```

Or as @ChrisA mentioned, you can also use, only thing is the pandas format is good already, so skipped that part:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.inv_date.str[:10], errors='coerce')
0    2008-01-24
1    2007-06-15
2    2007-08-06
3    2007-08-15
4    2008-02-15
5    2007-07-03
6    2007-08-13
Name: inv_date, dtype: object
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=['inv_date'], dayfirst=True)
df['inv_date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
0    24/01/2008
1    15/06/2007
2    08/06/2007
3    15/08/2007
4    15/02/2008
5    07/03/2007
6    13/08/2007
```

Hope this will help too.